# How to populate the properties of a collection inside a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model, `Sample` which contains a `List<QCItem>`, which is populated in the constructor.

In my `Sample.Create.cshtml` form, I have the following section, for populating the `Mass` values of each item in a `List<QCItem>`in the model:

```
@for (var itemCnt = 0; itemCnt < Model.Defects.Count(); itemCnt++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt], Model.Defects[itemCnt].Criteria)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt].Criteria, 
        new { @value = Model.Defects[itemCnt].Criteria })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt].Mass)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt].Mass)
}
```

While debugging, I can see that each item in `Model.Defects` in the controller for `Model` contains the `Mass` value I entered in the `TextBoxFor`, and also that each of these textboxes have the correct label next to them.

However, I also need each of these `QCItem`s to have `Criteria` assigned, which is why I added the `HiddenFor` field above, but when the debugger hits the controller, each of the `QCItem`s has a `Criteria` value of `null`.

How can I pass this value to the controller action in the same way that `Mass` is being passed? (It should automatically be assigned to the correct `QCItem`) The value definitely exists, as it is displayed in the `LabelFor`.

#### Update

This is the method in SampleController:

```
public ActionResult Insert(HttpPostedFileBase file, Sample sample)
{
    SelectedPallet = (Pallet)Session["pallet"];
    sample.Pallet = SelectedPallet;

    var access = new Access();
    access.InsertNewQCSample(sample);

    var files = Request.Files;
    // Insert into database

    return View("Details");
}
```

Here is the `Sample` model with all of its properties:

```
public class Sample : IGriddable
{
    private DataRow dataRow;
    private DataRow row;

    public string[] ColumnHeaders { get; } = new string[] { "SampleNumber", "Date", "ClerkStatus", "SupervisorStatus" };
    public string RowLinkPrefix { get { return $"/receiving/{Pallet.Grv.GrvNumber}/{Pallet.PalletSequence}/"; } }
    public bool Selectable { get; } = true;

    public Pallet Pallet { get; set; }
    public string Clerk { get; set; }
    public string MassOff { get; set; }
    public string ProductionComment { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor { get; set; }
    public string TechnicalComment { get; set; }

    public string SampleNumber { get; set; }
    public string ClerkStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorStatus { get; set; }

    public string ProductSpec { get; set; }

    // Each defect status needs to be saved as a (DB)subQCItems item
    public List<QCItem> Defects { get; set; } = new List<QCItem>();
    public List<string> ImagePaths { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Here is the `QCItem` model:

```
public class QCItem : IGriddable
{
    public string[] ColumnHeaders { get; } = new string[] { "Criteria", "Major", "Mass" };
    public string RowLinkPrefix { get; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Selectable { get; } = false;

    public string Criteria { get; internal set; }
    public bool Major { get; set; }
    public int Mass { get; set; }

    public Sample Sample;
}
```

Comment: Its just `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt].Criteria)` - never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. (and your `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt].Mass)` is pointless - you already have the textbox for that property, and your label makes no sense). You need to show your model and the signature of the POST method. Is `Criteria` and simple value type property?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your comment, it seems the issue was with `Criteria`s `set` being `internal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given your `Criteria` property and `internal` setter and the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set it (it needs to be `public`)

```
public string Criteria { get; set; }
```

Side notes:

Your `LabelFor()` method is not associating a the label with the textbox (clicking on it will not set focus. It needs to be

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt].Mass, Model.Defects[itemCnt].Criteria)
```

Your hidden input for `Criteria` should be just

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt].Criteria)
```

The hidden input for `Mass` is pointless and its value will be ignored by the `DefaultModelBinder` because your have a `TextBoxFor()` for the same property before the hidden input

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Stephen Muecke's comment (which gave a suggestion which I had already tried), I noticed that the `Criteria` property had an `internal` setter, which cannot be accessed from the view.

After changing this to

```
public string Criteria { get; set; }
```

and in the form:

```
@for (var itemCnt = 0; itemCnt < Model.Defects.Count(); itemCnt++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt], Model.Defects[itemCnt].Criteria)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt].Criteria)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Defects[itemCnt].Mass)
}
```

It now works fine